# Any good resources for learning about quantum networks and how to do a simulation of BB84 protocol?

Tags: resource-request, simulation, cryptography, bb84, quantum-networks

I'm a communication engineering student. And I'm thinking of doing my project on BB84 protocol but I don't know where to start. As a beginner, are there any documents or tutorials about quantum networks and how to use simulators like  QuISP or Simulaqron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good book about quantum networks (with a communication engineering flavour) is "Quantum Networking" by Rodney Van Meter.

Regarding SimulaQron, look at this simple tutorial for getting started:

https://softwarequtech.github.io/SimulaQron/html/GettingStarted.html

I strongly suggest to read the main paper on SimulaQron (https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.08032)
where the BB84 example is clearly illustrated.

Comment: I will check them, thanks for your help.